# C# Reflection: How to get the properties of the derived class from the base class

Tags: c#, reflection

Basically I just want to get the properties of the derived class with [Test]  attribute from the base class.

Here is my sample code:

```
namespace TestConsole
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        private System.Int64 _id;

        public BaseClass()
        { }

        [Test]
        public System.Int64 ID
        {
            get { return _id;}
            set { _id = value;}
        }

        public System.Xml.XmlNode ToXML()
        { 
            System.Xml.XmlNode xml = null;

            //Process XML here

            return xml;
        }
    }

    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        System.String _name;

        public DerivedClass()
        { }

        [Test]
        public System.String Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }
    }

    public class TestConsole
    {
        public static void main()
        {
            DerivedClass derivedClass = new DerivedClass();

            System.Xml.XmlNode xmlNode = derivedClass.ToXML();
        }
    }
}
```

I want the xmlNode to be something like this:

```
<root>
  <class name="DerivedClass">
    <Field name="Id">
    <Field name="Name">
  </class>
</root>
```

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you're trying to reinvent the wheel... Have you tried [XML serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx) ?

Comment: "Getting properties of a derived class from a base class" doesn't mean anything.  Only calling GetProperties on the type of the derived class can work.

Answer (score 8):

You can call `this.GetType().GetProperties()` and call `GetCustomAttributes()` on each `PropertyInfo` to find properties that have the attribute.

You will need to run the loop recursively to scan the properties of the base type.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that `XmlNode` is a good class for this purpose.
Firstly, **creating an XmlNode requires you to pass an XmlDocument for it, which is not a beatiful solution**.

Secondly, attributes and property values can be nicely extracted with LINQ and I think that this might integrate nicely with LINQ to XML (and, specifically, `XElement` class).

I wrote some code that does it:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
class PropertyAttribute : Attribute { }

class BaseClass
{
    [Property]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<XElement> PropertyValues {
        get {
            return from prop in GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                   where prop.GetGetMethod () != null
                   let attr = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PropertyAttribute), false)
                                  .OfType<PropertyAttribute>()
                                  .SingleOrDefault()

                   where attr != null
                   let value = Convert.ToString (prop.GetValue(this, null))

                   select new XElement ("field",
                       new XAttribute ("name", prop.Name),
                       new XAttribute ("value", value ?? "null")
                   );
        }
    }

    public XElement ToXml ()
    {
        return new XElement ("class",
               new XAttribute ("name", GetType ().Name),
               PropertyValues
               );
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    [Property]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var instance = new DerivedClass { Id = 42, Name = "Johnny" };
        Console.WriteLine (instance.ToXml ());
    }
}
```

This outputs the following XML to the console:

```
<class name="DerivedClass">
  <field name="Name" value="Johnny" />
  <field name="Id" value="42" />
</class>
```

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you didn't need values there. You'll need to remove value retrieving section there. However I still think this code sample is useful enough.

Comment: Your code is perfect for this. I just want to notice that "BindingFlags.Instance" is what does the trick of getting properties from the base class.